# How to extract the text value using regular expression extractor

Tags: regex, text-extraction, regular-language

I'm trying to extract some text value from a sentence, but i'm not getting any thing.

Please help me out to get out of it.

Below is the image and marked as red which text value i need to extract, I want to get the value of **VIEWSTATE** as given in image.
[image]

Comment: Without showing the regex you tried, how can we tell you why you are not getting anything?

Comment: Why not just use basic string manipulation? It's bound to be a lot simpler. Not that a regex is going to be very complex but it does seem to give you trouble.

Comment: You could pipe you text into:
grep -o "__VIEWSTATE|[^|]*"
or
sed "s/^.*|\(__VIEWSTATE|[^|]*\)|.*$/\1/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try using:

```
(?<=VIEWSTATE\|).*?\|
```

Or, if your regex engine/tool doesn't support lookbehinds, we can match on:

```
VIEWSTATE\|(.*?)\|
```

and then access the first capture group for the content you want.

Comment: Thank you @Tim, great solution!